# Fullscreen svg similar to object-fit cover

Tags: html, css, svg

I've read through a lot of questions and tutorials, but still couldn't figure out how to properly make an svg take the full screen and cover it (just like you would with `object-fit: cover` and in my case `object-position: 0`), so that there are no scrollbars visible. The only thing I managed to get was a non-scrollable fullscreen with the parts of the svg which could fit into it.

The svg is inside an `<object>`, as I need the links to work.

```
<div class="map">
  <object class="fullscreen-map" type="image/svg+xml" data="europe3.svg">
    Your browser does not support SVG
  </object>
</div>
```

The svg itself has no viewBox by default and has `width=1920` and `height=1080`, but I tried to include a viewBox with the same dimensions as well while trying out other stuff that I found.

[Here's a link to the SVG I'm trying to get to fullscreen](http://www.georgdonner.de/wp-content/themes/georgsite/images/europe3.svg)

The best I could come up with until now is to style the `<object>` around it, but it only crops and doesn't even try to scale the SVG:

```
.fullscreen-map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 1020px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 0;
    font-family: 'object-fit: cover;';
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I could get it to work by adding the SVG in an img tag, but then I'll lose the ability to click on links within it.

[So here is the expected result](http://www.georgdonner.de/map/) and as you can see, the positioning of the links to the different locations doesn't really work if you change the viewport aspect ratio to something different than 16:9. If you have suggestions how to implement that easily, I'd be really happy to hear them too :)

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Create an [MCVE] so we can see how far you have got.

Comment: I hope that's enough (:

Comment: `font-family: 'object-fit: cover;';`??

Comment: That's for Edge and IE, they don't support object-fit yet, but there's a JQuery plugin which deals with that and needs the information in a font-family attribute.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First change your CSS.  Remove the `object-fit` and `object-position` properties.

```
.fullscreen-map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 1020px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Next, you need to modify your SVG.  In the root `<svg>` tag, make the following changes:

1. Remove the `width` and `height` attributes.
2. Add the following attributes:

   ```
   viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
   ```

Your SVG should look like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
   id="svg3157"
   inkscape:version="0.92.1 r15371"
   sodipodi:docname="europe3.svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
  ...etc...
```

`preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"` is the equivalent of your `object-fit` settings for SVGs. The `viewBox` is needed so the browser knows how much it needs to scale the SVG contents`.

Comment: Just a short question: If I delete the `<object>` and put the svg into a div which has the same class `fullscreen-map`, the `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"` doesn't do anything anymore (it takes the whole width, but adjusts the height accordingly, keeping the aspect ratio). Why is that?

Comment: You need to add that class to the `<svg>`, not the `<div>`.  Otherwise, without any specified size, the SVG will choose one itself. It'll get the width from its parent (100vw), and the height from the width and the viewBox aspect ratio `(ie. 100vw * 1080/1920)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers Paul! Everything worked perfectly :)

Comment: If you need the scaled image to be centred in the available viewport (As an `img` will be with `object-fit: cover;`), using `xMidYMid` as opposed to `xMinYMin` will achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, another weird thing about SVGs.

Comment: If you need the scaled image to the bounds of the container, use `meet` instead of `slice`. E.g. this is equivalent to `object-fit: contain`: `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"`