# Masking the current svg component with an image

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have attempted to mask the svg component with the image but the width of the svg does not fill to 100%.

```
<svg
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  viewBox="0 0 23.25 10"
  style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
>
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <path d="M 15 -16.34 C 13.21 8.06, 20 18, -16.73 -5" fill="white" />
      <path d="M 50 25 C 13.1 -20.35, -5.17 10.46, 50 45" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image
    href={imgUrl}
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    mask="url(#mask)"
  />
</svg>
```

[Without masking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilj7C.png)

[With masking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB84W.png)


What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Your image won't automatically fill the entire width7height of the svg. Add ` preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` to your `<image>` to apply a  auto scaling similar to CSS `object-fit:cover`

Comment: This work as expected, can you explain a bit more what happens here? Also, can you answer this question so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: See PaulLeBeau's Answer here ["Fullscreen svg similar to object-fit cover"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348351/fullscreen-svg-similar-to-object-fit-cover#43367943) and ["How to Scale SVG - by Amelia Bellamy-Royds"](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)